# Can't call method "prepare" on an undefined value using Perl DBI

Tags: perl, dbi

I have a sub in a Perl module, Advancer.pm:

```
sub validate_extra {
    my ($dbh, $customer_id, $site) = @_;
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{
            SELECT key
            FROM master
            WHERE
                code = ?
                AND set = ?
                AND type_id = 2
                ORDER BY customer_id DESC, site DESC
            LIMIT 1
    });
    $sth->execute($customer_id, $site);
```

But when I call this module from a test (.t) I get an error:

> Can't call method "prepare" on an undefined value at Advancer.pm line 511.

```
 my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{
```

is line 511.

Comment: What's the call to `validate_extra` look like? At a glance, it looks like you're failing to pass in values, or failing to pass in a defined database handle. Have you verified that the database connection is made successfully?

Answer (score 5):

You're passing an undefined value for the first parameter to `validate_extra`.

Most obviously this would happen if your call was just

```
validate_extra();
```

but you may have passed the wrong variable by mistake, or perhaps the original connect has failed but gone unchecked:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:database=mydb', 'user', 'pass', {PrintError => 0});

validate_extra($dbh, $customer, $site);
```